# Are all EP plenary vote results publically accessible? Where?

Tags: european-union, parliament, europe, data-sources

Recently I struggled to find the EP vote results in case of [this regulation](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/procedure/EN/2017_122). Although it's marked as adopted on the [EUR-LEX website](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/procedure/EN/2017_122), none of the related votes I could find on [VoteWatch](https://www.votewatch.eu/) ended up positively for the regulation. Is there a way to find any EP plenary voting?

Comment: Not *all*, as there are secret ballots - but rarely..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Committee vote, 2nd reading](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/A-9-2020-0115_EN.html). the last table has it by group and EP name. It was 33 for, 15 against, 1 abstained, but the PPE vote appears to have been split on East-West lines (as you'd expect for this kind of road-freight debate) Romanians, Bulgarians, Hungarians and Poles voted against.

I (also) found the [plenary vote for the first reading](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/PV-8-2019-04-04-VOT_EN.pdf).
Final vote at this stage (p. 45) after all the amendments were voted individually was
"Vote: Commission proposal RCV + 394, 236, 5", which means adopted by roll-call vote, 394 for, 236 opposed, 5 abstained. The detailed roll-call votes (i.e. how each MEP voted) are in [a separate PDF](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/PV-8-2019-04-04-RCV_EN.pdf).

You're probably confused by the [plenary vote on the 2nd reading](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/PV-9-2020-07-09-VOT_EN.pdf) (pp. 8-9) as everything appears to have failed there. The catch is that on the 2nd reading the EP [automatically adopts](https://uk.practicallaw.thomsonreuters.com/1-503-0505?transitionType=Default&contextData=(sc.Default)&firstPage=true) the Council's version if the motion/proposal to dismiss and all amendments are rejected, which is what happened here (cf. [Article 294(7)(a)](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:12012E294&from=EN) of TFEU).

(If you wonder how I found all of those, I started with the [signature document](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/AUTO/?uri=consil:PE_25_2020_INIT), which is linked on the EUR-Lex page you've linked to, near the top. In the signature document you find the dates of when the votes happened, and you just have to look at the PDF summaries for those sessions, which get published [on the EP plenary page](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/plenary/en/votes.html?tab=votes). To access old proceedings, on the plenary index page you can use the calendar at the very bottom, although the URLs are pretty short and standardized, so you can just index that way too.

The long plenary PDF documents get published well before that data gets broken down into finer chunks on EU websites. For example, the more detailed info for the 2nd reading hasn't been percolated to the [regulation page yet](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/TA-9-2020-0185_EN.html), but the [one for the first reading has been](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/TA-8-2019-0340_EN.html), videos and everything. )