# How much of votes in the European Parliament fall on party (group) lines as opposed to country (groups) lines?

Tags: voting, statistics, european-parliament

[Some votes](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/60482/18373) in the European Parliament fall on geographical/country lines. I'm pretty sure (many) others probably fall on a more traditional ideological (e.g. left-right) divide between [EP party groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_groups_of_the_European_Parliament#9th_European_Parliament) (EPP being more to the right of PES etc.)

So, are there some statistics that try to tease how much voting goes on "party lines" vs some kind of "country lines" in the EP?

Comment: Just glancing at the example you linked makes me believe that that one too fell along a mostly ideological line with only the conservative parties being split by nationality …

Comment: Do you have votes/party per country? I could run the stats but am American and don't know where to find that